# Thwarting XSS using dynamic pre tags

Tags: javascript, xss

Per expert advise, the user content (`replyContent`) is enclosed in a `<pre>` tag to mitigate XSS as shown below. But why every one says the below code avoids XSS??

Anyway, I tried to inject with `</pre><script>alert("XSS");</script><pre>`, but it successfully thwarted the attempt and displayed the code fragment as such.

So, Is it sufficient (There is code already in place to strip off special characters like <,>,/,',& etc) or is there any way to circumvent this protection??

Any idea??

**Code Snippet:**

```
$row = $("<tr class='wp_replies_tr'></tr>"); 
...  
$msgColumn5 = $("<td width='112' class='wp_msgCol5'></td>");
$preTag = $("<pre class='wp_reply_content'></pre>");
$pre.text( replyContent );
$msgColumn5.html($pre);
$row.append($msgColumn5);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$pre.text( replyContent );` converts the input to HTML and therefore prevents injections ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-textString)). `$msgColumn5.html($pre);` uses the already sanitized `$pre`.

Comment: .text does createTextNode() which by default escapes the string, that is cool. So will it prevent 100% XSS??

Comment: @Aczire Yes, assuming there are no implementation issues